# safest way to create prepared statements connection

Tags: php, mysqli, database-connection, prepared-statement

I'm in the process of converting some queries to prepared statements and I currently have the following in a connect file:

```
<?php

DEFINE ('DB_USER' , 'blah');

DEFINE ('DB_PASSWORD' , 'blah');

DEFINE ('DB_HOST' , 'localhost');

DEFINE ('DB_NAME' , 'blah');

//make the connection

$dbc = mysqli_connect (DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME)
        OR die ('Could not connect to MySQL: ' .
        mysqli_connect_error() );

?>
```

Can I still use $dbc somehow?  I don't want to plaintext my connection information into a statement like this:

```
 $mysqli = new mysqli("heres", "all", "my", "sensitive", "information"):
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the sensitive information in a file that's not in the webroot.

And you could use SSL to connect to the mysql server

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ssl-connections.html